# Dynamic template loading Razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

suppose my page is like the following:

```
<div id="myFilter">
   country : a selectbox, where there is a list of countries
</div>

<div id="displayHotel">
  //First it will show details of hotel no 1 with form. after clicking 'nextBtn' it will propagate
</div>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
```

what I want is, if someone clicks the next button after filling up the form in 'displayHotel', it will go to the server, save things, then renders the second hotel with form in the 'displayHotel' div.

But the page shouldn't be refreshed. I dont want to call again for the country list.

only the 'displayHotel' div will be re-rendered.

Using Angular, Ember or any other JavaScript framework I can do it easily, but is there a way to do it with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Have you read up on `@Ajax.BeginForm()`? If not [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3) is some guidance.

Comment: No.. I'm a beginner and just started 2 days back. Haven't use @Ajax.BeginForm(). Will try it.
Can we use partial view for this @jacqijw

Comment: Yes you can use a partial view with `@Ajax.BeginForm()`, however it is not necessary.